# WAS for Bluemix cannot connect to database

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, secure-gateway, ibm-was-oc

I'm getting an Error:Connection timeout message when going from WAS for Bluemix to DB2 on prem.

**WAS Environment**

WAS for Bluemix

WAS Base Plan (V8.5.5.7 tWAS)

Secure Gateway Service 1.4.1

**DB2 Environment**

Windows Environments.

DB2 Enterprise Server V10.5

This environment also has Secure Gateway client 1.4.1 installed.
The access from secure gateway client on DB2 environment to services on Bluemix is no probrem.

I think Bluemix cannot recognize the address and port of the DB2 environment because ping is not responsive.

Why would this occur? Is there any other config needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With WAS for Bluemix, once we hand over the image to the client, the client controls their own configuration.  The issue here is that the port with which you're trying to connect is probably closed.   The initial pattern provided only has ports opened for the most commonly used ports.  When connecting to DBs, it is the client's responsibility to ensure the needed ports are open.  See the following:

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/ApplicationServeronCloud/index.html#cellConventions

You should be able to run the following commands from the WAS for Bluemix Guest:

```
export serverPorts=<portNumber>TCP,<portNumber>:UDP
sudo /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/virtual/bin/openFirewallPorts.sh -ports $serverPorts -persist true
```

Comment: Typo above, it should be <portNumber>colonTCP,<portNumber>colonUDP